# Why are subsequent edit conflicts included in a user’s rejected suggestions total?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, community-user

If “Community” rejects an edit because it “conflicted with a subsequent edit”, that’s okay and an indication for healthy participation. The reasons for these rejects have been discussed multiple times. Yet I wonder and didn’t find an answer:

**Why are “Community”-rejected edit suggestions considered in a user’s reject total?**

If reviewers reject suggestions on grounds of non-improvement, it’s good to take note of that. A versioning conflict however is no misjudgment and certainly not something to hold against an editor.

I wonder why this is so and if there’s a specific reason why there is no distinction.

Comment: Because the edit _was_ rejected. It was _automatically rejected,_ instead of rejected by a reviewer, but it was still rejected. Yeah, it's not quite the learning experience of a reviewer reject, but you can still look at the question and see what the other editor did, and perhaps learn from it. (Or fix it if they made a horrible edit.) It at least does not count against you for the purposes of an edit ban.

Comment: @Kendra: How can you tell the reject happened because the other edit was found to be *far* more valuable? Isn’t it rather choosing one edit as the “victim” for an impossible merge (even when the two edits highly overlap)?

Comment: In most cases, it's a <2k rep editor versus a 2k rep editor- The full editor's edit tends to be taken in that case because it's applied immediately. In the case of two suggested edits, I don't know. Not sure I've even seen that one happen. So it's not necessarily a matter of which edit is better, it's a matter (most of the time) of the privileges of the editors. (In the case of an OP edit, that takes priority over the suggested edit because, regardless of rep, the OP's edits are applied as if they had full edit privileges.)

Comment: @Kendra: Keep the “too long” version coming, no need not to read it. Thanks for this plausible explanation. However, “can’t” doesn’t answer the above question, while the other comment does.

Comment: In that case, I'll just remove the second comment. :) Glad the first gives some explanation.

Comment: Note that edit conflicts are not (as far as I know) taken into account for automatic suggestion bans. So there is at least one important way in which they are treated separately from other rejections already.